# SOUT Shortcut in Netbeans for Javascript

Tags: javascript, netbeans, shortcut

In Java with Netbeans I often use sout + Tab to autotype System.out.println(). Is there a similar abbreviation for Javascript console.log() in Netbeans? Or how could it be set in the IDE?

Comment: Also made a shortcut "cona" + Tab for console.assert(boolean, text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to :     `Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templates`

Select your language and set abbreviation. There are plenty of examples to learn how to create your own.

Comment: Thanks. Any standard industry abbreviation for that (I stopped at clog)?

Comment: For console.log there is 'conl' - 'window.console.log(${log});'